# Why is $O(nk)$ an upper bound for the $k$-gossip problem?

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I am studying the $k$-gossip problem on dynamic graphs against an adaptive adversary. Essentially, we are given a set of tokens $\mathcal{T}$ which are distributed amongst the nodes such that each token is distributed to at least one node. Importantly, the nodes do not know the value of $k$. The problem is solved when all nodes know all $k$ tokens.

The paper [Information Spreading in Dynamic Networks](https://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/rraj/Pubs/TokenForwarding.pdf) write in their abstract:

> Our main result is an $\Omega(nk/\log{n})$ lower bound on the number of rounds
> needed for any deterministic token-forwarding algorithm to solve
> $k$-gossip. This resolves an open problem raised in [33], improving
> their lower bound of $\Omega(n\log{k})$, and matching their upper bound of
> $O(nk)$ to within a logarithmic factor.

[The paper they mention](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rotem/dynamicgraphs.pdf) for the $O(nk)$ upper bound gives a protocol for $n$-gossip but not for $(k<n)$-gossip. Is there an easy way to see the $O(nk)$ upper bound for $k$-gossip for dynamic graphs?

We know that $1$-gossip can be solved in $n-1$ rounds, where $n$ is the size of the network if the nodes know $n$. So could we maybe do $1$-gossip $k$ times. The only issue is that the nodes do not know $n$ or $k$, so we can't use this approach.